# How to check multiples itens of an array?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, httparty

everyone, I'm trying to check an information from every item of an array but I don't know how to do this for all the 4 items, first that's the standard response:

```
data: [{"optinId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",  "name": "string",  "description": string",  "alertMessage": "string",  "master": true,  "optin": true}]
```

this example has only 1 item but the true I have has 4, what I have to do is **"expect when MASTER=true then OPTIN=true"**, I started with a simple IF:

```
 if (response["data"][0]["master"]=true)  
 expect(@response["data"][0]["optin"]).to eql true
 end
```

that solution isn't enough for me because I want to check all 4 items of the array, can someone please help me with a solution?

Comment: if the request defined to return 4 items all the time when master = true, then i suggest you to make assertions manually. This way your test will be more explicit and less buggy.

Comment: master will be true only in one of the four items. "master=boolean" is present in every item

Comment: so as i understand, you need to loop through to data find the item that its master attribute has true value and assert that item's optin value right?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it

Comment: Just as a future note `response["data"][0]["master"]=true` will always result in: a) `NoMethodError` (if any part of the chain does not match); or b) `true` becuase `=` is assignment not equality so you are assigning the key `"master"` to reference the value `true`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the item you want with `.find` method and assert the fields you want.

```
item = response[:data].find { |item| item[:master] }
expect(item&.dig(:optin)).to eql(true)
```

This code will assert there must be a item with master true and optin true

Comment: got method "find" not found

Comment: can you share the complete error message?

Comment: undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: make sure that `response[:data]` isnt nil. if your keys are not symbol try to call as string like this: `response['data']`

Comment: the problem was (true), removing brackets made it work

Comment: i dont think so. error message clearly indicates that error came from the  `response[:data].find`.

Comment: I first changed [:data] to ["data"] and the error persisted, then I changed (true) to true and  it worked

Answer (score 0):

try iterating through items in the array, using a for loop or for each

example:

```
arr = [{"optinId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",  "name": "string",  "description": string",  "alertMessage": "string",  "master": true,  "optin": true}]

arr.each do |item|
  /** your code **/
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
item = @response["data"].find { |item| item["master"]==true }
expect(item["optin"]).to eql true
```

that solved my problem, thanks to Mehmet Adil Istikbal and everyone else that contribute